# hudson | nAnt.exe is not on the "\bin" folder

Tags: nant, hudson

I just setup hudson (CI), how do I tell this Dude that my NAnt.exe is not in the \bin folder?

**it's keep looking for this path:**

```
C:\myProjects\web2009\tools\nant\bin\NAnt.exe //doesn't exist
```

**but in the reality I setup it, in here:**

```
C:\myProjects\web2009\tools\nant\NAnt.exe  // the correct path
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Hudson configuration page?  It should be configurable there:

```
http://hudson:8080/configure
```

The Nant plugin has a [wiki page](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org//display/HUDSON/NAnt+Plugin) which says in part:

```
In order to use this plugin, you need to first 
configure a NAnt installation, which can be done on 
the Hudson Configuration page.  Simply specify a name 
for the installation, and the path to the installation 
directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Wiki Page answer to simply specify a name and path is NOT enough.

It seems that the installation path for the NANT HOME makes an "assumption" that there is a further \bin folder where the actual EXE is located. We all know what happens when you make an assumption.

So, for example:

My nant was located in

C:\Code\Projects\Learning_Hudson\tools\nant

and I kept getting errors, even though that was the same path I used in my NANT HOME config value. But I did keep getting a "not a directory" error on my NANT HOME with the above path.
So, after searching for an answer, which I didn't find, I found this question and it helped me figure out to MOVE my nant files to a bin subdirectory.

C:\Code\Projects\Learning_Hudson\tools\nant\bin - is where I moved the nant files

and the I left the NANT_HOME configuration path as

C:\Code\Projects\Learning_Hudson\tools\nant

and that got ride of the errors, and I finally got a successful build after 12 attempts, and lots of configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

Hudson seems to expect NANT_HOME to point to a folder that contains a bin directory where nant.exe can be found.

This confused me as well at first, but I just moved my Nant\bin folder to the appropriate location to get Hudson to save the setting. (I'd imagine you can do the same thing to get your setup working.)